# Powershell duplicate image scanner

Tags: image, powershell

So I have made this Duplicate image scanner using powershell. It will operate using the SHA256 hashes of the files.

Any tips or suggestions on making this more dynamic/robust/efficient or adding new features would be greatly appreciatied!

```
$sig=@'
public static void ShowConsoleWindow(int state)
{
  var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
  ShowWindow(handle,state);
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
'@
$hc=Add-Type -mem $sig -name Hide -Names HideConsole -Ref System.Runtime.InteropServices -Pas
$hc::ShowConsoleWindow(0)
[console]::title="Duplicate Image Scanner (c) Wasif Hasan | Sep 2020"
$eXt=@('.jpg','.png','.gif','.jpeg','.webp','.tiff','.psd','.raw','.bmp','.heif','indd','.svg')
@('system.windows.forms','system.drawing')|%{add-type -as $_}
$s=[windows.forms.form]::new();$s.size=[drawing.size]::new(400,850);$s.StartPosition="CenterScreen";$s.Text="Select drives to scan"
$drives=gdr -p "FileSystem"|select -eXp name
$top=20;$left=50;$drives|%{
$c=$_.split(" ")-join"_";$top += 20
iex "`$$($c) = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox;`$$($c).Top = $($top);`$$($c).Left = $($left);`$$($c).Anchor='Left,Top';`$$($c).Parent='';`$$($c).Text='$($_)';`$$($c).Autosize=`$true;if('$_' -in `$drives){`$$c.Checked=`$true};`$s.Controls.Add(`$$c)"}
$ok=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;$ok.Text='OK';$ok.Top=770;$ok.Left=290
$ok.add_click({$s.Close()});$s.Controls.AddRange($ok)
$sa=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;$sa.Text='Select All';$sa.Top=770;$sa.Left=200
$sa.add_click({$s.Controls|?{($_.Checked) -or !($_.Checked)}|%{try{$_.Checked=$True}catch{}}});$s.Controls.AddRange($sa)
$null=$s.ShowDialog()
$choices=$s.Controls|?{$_.Checked}|select -eXp Text
$i=0;$choices|%{$choices[$i]=$_+':\';$i++}
$f=[windows.forms.form]::new();$f.Size=[drawing.size]::new(600,100);$f.StartPosition="CenterScreen";$f.Text="Please wait"
$l=[windows.forms.label]::new();$l.Text="Please wait until the scan is complete........";$l.Font="Segoe UI,16";$l.AutoSize=$true;$f.Controls.AddRange($l)
$null=$f.ShowDialog()
$files=@();$hCols=@();$choices|%{
dir $_ -r|?{$_.eXtension-in$eXt}|%{
$h=get-filehash $_.fullname -a 'SHA256'|select -eXp hash
if($h-in$hCols){$files+=$_.fullName}else{$hCols+=$h}
}};$f.Close()
$del=$files|ogv -t "Duplicate images (Hold CTRL and select the ones to delete)" -p
$del|%{rm "$_" -fo}
[windows.forms.messagebox]::Show("Thanks for using!","Duplicate image scanner","OK","Information")
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a powershell issue or a coding style issue (I’ve never used powershell), but this looks more like a sea of letters than a program. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you some advice:

- First of all you should make your code much more rideable. I am struggling to actually read this code. You should name your variables meaningfully, so the code can be read like English.
- Don't write multiple commands on a single line. It is easier to keep track of code when single command per line is used.
- When writing PowerShell scripts don't use cmdlet aliases, use full names of cmdlets. Different people use different aliases, but all of them know full names of cmdlets.